# Spree Commerce, Perform a search for payment methods using zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

In my region, we use a different way to organize countries/states and zones.

It is way more relevant to ask the customer directly for his zone on the address form.. This is why I need to perform a search for all shipping methods that correspond to said zone. The problem is that I cannot understand the way the relationship is made, maybe due to lack of knowledge with apis. Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do I perform a search for all shipping methods that correspond to a zone?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Spree zone is a bunch of states (one or many). So for a given coutry, you can have many zones.

Then for a Spree shipping method, you can associate it to one or more zones.